# How to import graph from another class in Kivy?

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

I would like to import graph from NiceGraph class to .kv file, but I have not idea, how to do that.

I readed documentation, but I couldn't find anything about using class in class.

Here's my try.

```
class NiceGraph(BoxLayout):
    graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', x_ticks_minor=5,
    x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
    y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=5,
    x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1)
    plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]
    graph.add_plot(plot)

class KivyTesting(BoxLayout):
    pass

class KivyTestingApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return KivyTesting()

kivy_testing_app = KivyTestingApp()
kivy_testing_app.run()
```

And there's .kv file

```
<KivyTesting>:
    orientation: 'vertical'
    padding: 10
    slider_colors: 0, 0, 0
    canvas.before:
        Color:
            rgb: root.slider_colors
        Rectangle:
            pos: root.pos
            size: root.size

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 200
        Slider:
            size_hint_x: 2
            max: 1
            value: 0
            on_value: root.slider_colors[0] = self.value
        Slider:
            size_hint_x: 2
            max: 1
            min: 0
            value: 0
            on_value: root.slider_colors[1] = self.value
        Slider:
            size_hint_x: 2
            max: 1
            min: 0
            value: 0
            on_value: root.slider_colors[2] = self.value

    BoxLayout:
        size_hint_y: 600
        NiceGraph:
            graph:
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
class NiceGraph(BoxLayout):
    global graph

    graph = Graph(xlabel='X', ylabel='Y', 
    x_ticks_minor=5,
    x_ticks_major=25, y_ticks_major=1,
    y_grid_label=True, x_grid_label=True, padding=5,
    x_grid=True, y_grid=True, xmin=-0, xmax=100, ymin=-1, ymax=1)
    plot = MeshLinePlot(color=[1, 0, 0, 1])
    plot.points = [(x, sin(x / 10.)) for x in range(0, 101)]
    graph.add_plot(plot) 

class KivyTesting(BoxLayout):
    graph1 = graph
```

and work with `root.graph1` object in `<KivyTesting>:`